# RuntimeException in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am using `AsyncTask` for a long running task but I am getting the following error.

```
error in doInBackground====java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Why am I getting that error and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can access GUI only from OnPostExecute and OnProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running the task inside a non-UI thread.

The UI thread is set so that it loops. You can see where's the loop in a stack trace or in ddms while debugging:

```
...
MessageQueue.next() line: 146
Looper.loop() line: 110
...
```

This loop takes care of handling the messages, like the ones that an `AsyncTask` sends, with a `Handler`, like the one the `AsyncTask` is trying to set. If you're launching the task on a thread that has no looper set you get that message.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error comes when you change UI from asyntask which is not allowed, other way is to implement handler instead asyntask...

Comment: Imprecise, you are not allowed to modify UI from everywhere in the `AsyncTask` but you are allowed to do it in `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` like @Lukas mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't post your code, so hard to find issue.

I think because you access UI Thread in`DoInBackground.` (for example: you access TextView, or Button, or EditText....) This is a most common error when use Asyntask.

you should post some parameter to `publishProgress` in `DoInBackGround`. then `asyntask` will send this param to `onProgressUpdate` and this method will act on UI Thread